# HTML 5 Local Storage - deleting after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am a beginner to javascript, html5, and jquery and am trying to use locale storage for the first time in an app that I am designing. However, once I added the "getIncomeArray" function to my code, the local storage would get deleted after I refreshed...
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jviro/94wtpe2w/)

```
function getIncomeArray(){

  //get or create storage arrays
  var incomeArray = localStorage.getItem["incomeArray"];
  console.log(incomeArray);
  if (!incomeArray) {

    incomeArray = [];
    localStorage.setItem("incomeArray", JSON.stringify(incomeArray));
    //code
    console.log("there is no array so I made one");
  }
  else{
    incomeArray = JSON.parse(incomeArray);
    console.log("there is an array and I parsed it");
  }

return incomeArray;
}
```

Comment: I was adding the array but not the actual value to local storage. It's good now

Comment: Oh, so it works now? It was kinda difficult to work with `localStorage` on JSFiddle because it sometimes used the domain `jsfiddle.net` and sometimes `fiddle.jshell.net`…

Answer (score 1):

Unless you put a typo into your original question, your call to getItem should be normal brackets, not square brackets, for example: `var incomeArray = localStorage.getItem("incomeArray")`

Its more than likely because of that, your variable is undefined which would go into the setItem clause

Comment: Yes, I can get why this would be a typo… the `getItem` method is a function that returns a property and `[]` is a property accessor… kind of similar, so the OP probably confused the two.

Comment: It seems that is the problem, but I thought I'd ask, just to make sure it was the case :-)

Comment: It was definitely the problem. Thanks for your help! I am having an issue when I am retrieving the data from local storage. It's coming up as undefined...

Comment: JSON.parse should get you the array object back, you could then alert income array.length to see if there's anything inside, as it may be the array is empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
var incomeArray = localStorage.getItem["incomeArray"];
```

`getItem` is a function with the key name as its *argument* so use round parantheses:

```
var incomeArray = localStorage.getItem("incomeArray");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that I missed that. It's data isn't getting erased anymore, which is awesome. However, when I try try to print my items from localstorage they come back as "undefined"